# ASWebAuthenticationSession on iOS 13

Tags: ios, objective-c, flutter

I installed iOS 13, the authentication via Safari no longer works.
I have the same configuration on iOS 12 except `self.authSessionAS.presentationContextProvider = self;`

```c
self.authSessionAS = [[ASWebAuthenticationSession alloc]initWithURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:self.authUrl] callbackURLScheme:@"app://" completionHandler:^(NSURL * _Nullable callbackURL, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if(callbackURL)
    {
        self.resultStream(callbackURL.absoluteString);
    }else
    {
        self.resultStream(@"");
    }
    self.resultStream = NULL;
}];

self.authSessionAS.presentationContextProvider = self;
[self.authSessionAS start];
```

Comment: Agreed. Have some code that runs on both iOS 12 and 13... 

With iOS 12, it correctly detects the cookie and uses it to prefill the login screen.
With iOS 13, it doesn't detect the cookie and presents the default login screen.

Presumably a bug in iOS 13...

Comment: Addendum... If the app is compiled in Xcode 10 (iOS 12 release) then ASWebAuthenticationSession broadly works on iOS 13 (although it doesn't pick up the cookie).

Comment: Compared to Xcode 11, where ASWebAuthenticationSession doesn't work on iOS 13 at all -- completely broken. Don't know what happens if compiled on Xcode 11 and run on iOS 12.

Comment: I find this solution https://dev.to/robotsquidward/quick-guide-to-aswebauthenticationsession-api-changes-in-ios-13-4m8i, but I don't know how to implement it in objective-c and flutter.

Comment: For flutter developers, check https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_web_auth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find a solution

Add above the implementation.

```c
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 130000
@interface AppDelegate() <ASWebAuthenticationPresentationContextProviding>
@end
#endif
```

In your code for Auth.

```c
self.authSessionAS = [[ASWebAuthenticationSession alloc]initWithURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:self.authUrl] callbackURLScheme:@"app://" completionHandler:^(NSURL * _Nullable callbackURL, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if(callbackURL)
    {
        self.resultStream(callbackURL.absoluteString);
    }else
    {
        self.resultStream(@"");
    }
    self.resultStream = NULL;
}];

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 130000
if (@available(iOS 13, *)) {
    self.authSessionAS.presentationContextProvider = self;
}
#endif

[self.authSessionAS start];
```

Add method

```c
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 130000
#pragma mark - ASWebAuthenticationPresentationContextProviding
- (ASPresentationAnchor)presentationAnchorForWebAuthenticationSession:(ASWebAuthenticationSession *)session  API_AVAILABLE(ios(13.0)){
   return UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow;
}
#endif
```

Comment: What's the difference between using `#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 130000` or `if #available(iOS 13.0, *)`?

Answer (score -1):

within `UIScene` sometimes it's hard to determine the right context and all samples above may not work as expected.

```
import AuthenticationServices
import UIKit

public protocol AuthContextProvider where Self: ASWebAuthenticationPresentationContextProviding {

  func clear()
}

final class ContextProvider: NSObject, AuthContextProvider {

  private var context: ASPresentationAnchor?

  // MARK: - ASWebAuthenticationPresentationContextProviding

  public func presentationAnchor(for session: ASWebAuthenticationSession) -> ASPresentationAnchor {
    let window = UIWindow()
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    self.context = window
    return window
  }

  public func clear() {
    context = nil
  }
}
```

then somewhere in u'r code:

```
  var contextProvider: AuthContextProvider?
  var session: NSObject?
```

and in func with auth call

```
  let session = ASWebAuthenticationSession(url: url, callbackURLScheme: callbackScheme) {
    url, error in

    if #available(iOS 13, *) {
      self.contextProvider?.clear() // clear context
    }

    completion(url, error)
  }

  self.session = session // retain session

  if #available(iOS 13, *) {
    self.contextProvider = ContextProvider() // retain context
    session.presentationContextProvider = self.contextProvider
  }

  session.start()
```